# Esperanto KER Exams

Tags: ker-exams

How realistic a goal is it for an intermediate esperantist to aim for the KER C1 exam some months ahead?   How good do you have to be and how do you know when you have got there?
How much study did you do before taking the C1?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to pass it quite easily 14 months after I started learning Esperanto. My progress at the language was very quick at first, as I finished the Duolingo as well as several Memrise courses, and got to a decent level from just that. However, the real progress came quite a bit later, when I started properly using the language and attending meetups. If I had done that more actively from the start, and perhaps a bit more of it generally, I would have been able to pass the exam sooner than after 14 months, especially starting from when I was already an intermediate Esperantist.

I'd say it's quite doable in a few months, if you practice in the right way. Make sure you have practice partners you can really use the language with actively, be it writing or, perhaps even better, speaking it. If you do that, and make sure you learn enough vocabulary through it or in other ways, I think you should be able to pass C1 level quite easily.

Keep in mind, by the way, that you will also need to remember how to write a letter and some other practical bits of knowledge not directly related to Esperanto; make sure to look at example exams online so you'll have all the relevant skills (I wanted to link them, but I could not find them anymore! I hope they're still around somewhere.)

Themes and tables on what to know/learn: [clicky](http://edukado.net/upload/enhavo/dosieroj/C1_temoj_lingv_postuloj.pdf)

---

Mi kapablis sufiĉe facile sukcesi je ĝi 14 monatojn post kiam mi unue eklernis Esperanton. Mia progreso je la lingvo unue estis tre rapide, finante la kurson de Duolingo kaj kelkajn de Memrise, kaj mi atingis iom bonan nivelon pro nur tio. Tamen, mi vere progresis iom pli poste, kiam mi komencis efektive uzi la lingvon kaj ĉeesti kunvenojn. Se mi farus tion pli vigle de la komenco, kaj simple ĝenerale pli, mi povus sukcesi je la ekzameno pli frue ol post 14 monatoj, speciale post kiam mi jam estis meznivela esperantisto.

Laŭ mi, estas sufiĉe fareble en kelkaj monatoj, se oni sin ekzercas ĝuste. Gravas havi iun, kun kiu oni povas sin ekzerci per aktiva uzado de la lingvo, ĉu per skribado, ĉu, eĉ pli bone, per parolado. Se oni faras tion, kaj lernas sufiĉe da vortoj tiel aŭ aliamaniere, laŭ mi oni sufiĉe facile povus sukcesi je la nivelo C1.

Parenteze, ne forgesu, ke oni bezonas ankaŭ scii kiel skribi leteron kaj kelkajn aliajn praktikajn sciendaĵojn ne rekte rilatajn al Esperanto; pristudu la ekzemplajn ekzamenojn rete por havi la ĝustajn kapablojn (mi volis ligi al ili, sed ne plu povis trovi ilin! Mi esperas ke ili ankoraŭ estas haveblaj ie.)

Temoj kaj tabloj pri lingvokonaj postuloj: [klaku](http://edukado.net/upload/enhavo/dosieroj/C1_temoj_lingv_postuloj.pdf)