# Any experience and advice on KER B exam?

Tags: ker-exams

Could someone who has successfully passed the Esperanto KER B1 or B2 exam share some experience? Any preparation advice? How long it took to prepare (from starter)? Any strategies, areas to focus or mistakes to avoid?

Comment: Although not exactly the same question you asked, you might still be interested in this other question and answer, which was about a similar topic: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/esperanto-ker-exams/3048.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the B2 exam in 2016 (written only, as they were not offering the oral exam).  I had studied Esperanto for just under 2 years.

It wasn't that hard.  I did much better than I thought I would, and I don't think it is that much more difficult than B1.  If you can read a magazine article and write a letter with only occasional reference to a dictionary, you shouldn't have too much trouble with B2.  However, if I had not been able to use the dictionary during the exam, it would have been harder.  I referred to it maybe 6 or 7 times.

No specific strategies.  Just take the practice exam.